# Kotlin Multiplatform Library issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created my own cross-platform library, for android and IOS, I want to import this library into an existing android project in the form of a module. But as soon as I add it I get an error Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.2', apply: false] was not found. I have already changed the version of kotlin and gradle plugin too. My existing application is not cross-platform.  Maybe someone can suggest a solution to this problem?

I try to do:

- Change gradle plugin version.
- Change kotlin version.

Comment: did you try version 8.2.0? also gradle shouldn't be in offline mode

Comment: Yes i try this , but i take same issue

Comment: it's hard to help you without any details - add your gradle config files - perfectly they should be [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)